# Access dynamic filtering listbox with double where clause

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a dynamic textbox filtering function in VBA

```
Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = "SELECT qry_allUtilities.ID, qry_allUtilities.Supplier AS Lieferant, qry_allUtilities.Cabinet AS Ablageort, qry_allUtilities.Size AS Grösse, qry_allUtilities.WorkingLength AS Nutzlänge, qry_allUtilities.Description AS Bezeichnung "
sSQL = sSQL & "  FROM qry_allUtilities "
If Not sFilter = "" Then
    Dim arrFilter
    arrFilter = Split(sFilter, "+")
    Dim varWort
    For Each varWort In arrFilter
        If Not varWort = "" Then
            Dim sWort As String
            sWort = varWort
            sSQL = sSQL & " AND [ID] & ' ' & [Supplier] & ' ' & [Floor] & ' ' & [Cabinet] & ' ' & [Size] & ' ' & [WorkingLength] LIKE '*" & sWort & "*'"
        End If
    Next
    sSQL = Replace(sSQL, " AND ", " WHERE ", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
End If
ctlListe.RowSource = sSQL
```

and would like to extend this with another `WHERE` clause because I have to exclude the records with `qry_allUtilities.InActive=False`

How do I do this? I always keep getting null or it won't exclude the records with `InActive=True` :/

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. There can be only 1 WHERE clause with multiple criteria. You should use indentation in code for easier reading, as I show in my edit of your question.

Comment: You did not include what `sFilter` is equal to when this is run. Please include that in your question.

Comment: @June7 so there is no way to use a text search with multiple criteria and my try to exclude some records? ... braX can't tell you right now, left the file at the office

Comment: What is the query defined as (the select statement)? Is `InActive` even a field in the query? If not, then you cannot use it in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Of course you can have additional criteria to exclude records, assuming InActive is a field in dataset. `WHERE Inactive=False AND …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this to add a variable (but unknown) number of filter options:

```
strFilter = ""    ' build the filter string in here

if <first condition reason is true> then 
    strFilter = strFilter + first condition + " AND "
end if

if <second condition reason is true> then 
    strFilter = strFilter + <second condition> + " AND "
end if 

' finish up
if len(strFilter) > 0 then    ' some critera are valid
    strFilter = Left(strFilter, Len(strFilter) - 5) ' chop off the spare " AND "
    strFilter = " WHERE " + strFilter    ' put the " WHERE " on the front
' else   ' no where clause
end if
```

Note that the spaces either side of the " AND " and " WHERE " are important.